# GA4: Data API - Managing Reporting

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to get data of users and average session duration for specific **hostName** which can change for every site that is deployed on our subdomain. I used the below request but issue is if a increase date range for one month the data that I was able to see in weekly date range now disappears and its not showing data for all dates when a larger date range is selected

```
const [response] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
                property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
                [ { startDate: '2023-10-25', endDate: '2023-11-24' } ],
                [
                {
                  name: 'hostName',
                },
                ['weekly', 'daily', 'mothly'].includes(dateFilter) ? { name: 'date' } : (dateFilter =='yearly' || !dateFilter) ? { name: 'yearMonth' } : { name: 'date' }
            ],
                [
                 { name: 'totalUsers' },
                 { name: 'averageSessionDuration' },
                    ],
                dimensionFilter: {
                    filter: {
                        fieldName: 'hostName',
                        stringFilter: {
                            matchType: 'PARTIAL_REGEXP',
                            value: subdomain,
                            caseSensitive: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

I existingly had an UA property and now I have GA4 property, is it issue of data migration which I dnt think so is because I have the data on dashboard as well and when gave date range for october it also gives data for some of the days of october as well